# Vue 3: v-once in for loop prints duplicated values

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

do I do something wrong or is it a bug? I think it is a bug.
The following code returns 2 divs with same text: 'test1'. Because of the 'v-once'. Every div should have corresponding string instead.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const testArray = ref([{
id:1,
string: 'test 1'
},{
id:2,
string: 'test 2'
}])
</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="obj in testArray" :key='obj.id'>
        <span v-once>{{obj.string}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Playground:

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Answer (score 0):

Move your `v-once` to the div with the `v-for` on it.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const testArray = ref(
  [
    {
    id:1,
    str: 'test 1'
    },
    {
    id:2,
    str: 'test 2'
        }
  ]
);  
</script>

<template>
    <div v-for="(obj) in testArray" :key='obj.id' v-once>       
        <span >{{obj.str}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: It will still render two divs?

Comment: Yes, but then everything inside will be unchangeable. I want something to change. Only one portion to be unchangeable.

Comment: @saibbyweb yes it will. Check the sandbox I added.

Answer (score 0):

It's rendering two divs because you are looping through an array having two objects. It's rendering a single div (once) for every iteration.

`v-once` directive is used to render the element `only once` which means after rendering it will be treated as static element.

If you make any to change `testArray`, after its rendered, the changes wont be visible on the DOM. I have updated your code, you can check it out in the below link. I am rendering the same text twice, one with `v-once` and another without it. You can see the one with `v-once` does not update on button click.

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. I want the span to be static and unchangeable. But I need it to be the correct values.

Comment: Oh! my bad. Apparently, the moment you use `v-once` with an element inside a loop, the iterations continue but the `index` stops updating for that element. Even calls to a function return cached results. It's probably by design. Using Vue's reactivity (dynamic list rendering) to output a static element would be an anti-pattern and should be avoided.